# Multiple bar charts side by side chartjs

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to create a bar chart that is grouped by the dataset rather than the label in chartjs3 and I'm having no luck. Before I switch over to building in D3, I wanted to check if this achievable within the confines of ChartJS.

[image: chartjs bar chart example]

Here is a link to a fiddle where I've been playing around with using different dataset structures and options from the Bar chart docs. I suspect that this is outside of the scope of the charting library, or is within the scope, but requires some custom components to be made – I would appreciate if anyone could direct me on what in particular I would need to extend (e.g. is it a case of a custom axes? or more?).

https://jsfiddle.net/f34ucs76/2/

```
const data = {
  labels: [
    '2000','2010','2020',
    // 'Frogs','Monkeys','Squirrels','Bats'
  ],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Frogs',
      data: [30.2,20.8,36.2],
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      //stack: 'Frogs',
    },
    {
      label: 'Monkeys',
      data: [16.3,13.0,22.3],
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
      //stack: 'Monkeys',
    },
    {
      label: 'Squirrels',
      data: [5.8,3.1,14.9],
      backgroundColor: 'cyan',
      //stack:'Squirrels',
    },
    {
      label: 'Bats',
      data: [0.1,3.6,2.6],
      backgroundColor: 'aquamarine',
      //stack:'Bats',
    },
  ],
}

const options = {
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  responsive: true,
  interaction: {
    intersect: false,
    mode: 'index',
  },
  plugins: {
    title: {
      display: false,
    },
    subtitle: {
      display: true,
      align: 'start',
      text: ['Source: Animals Index, June 2022'],
      font: {
        size: 12,
        style: 'italic',
      },
      position: 'bottom',
      padding: {
        top: 20,
      },
    },
    legend: {
      display: true,
      position: 'bottom',
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: true,
    },
  },
  scales: {
    x: {
      grid: {
        display: false,
      },
    },
    y: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Horsepower',
      },
    },
  },
}

const mychart = new Chart(
  document.getElementById('mychart'),
  {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: options,
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem can be solved with Chart.js but the `labels` and the single `dataset` need to be generated.

Further you need to define your own `legend` by defining a `plugins.legend.labels.generateLabels` together with with a `plugins.legend.labels.onClick` function.

> For further information, consult the [Legend](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.9.1/configuration/legend.html) page from the Chart.js. documentation.

Please take a look at your amended and runnable code below and see how it works.

```js
const baseData = {
  labels:  ['2000','2010','2020'],
  datasets: [
    { label: 'Frogs', data: [30.2, 20.8, 36.2], bgColor: 'red', hidden: false },
    { label: 'Monkeys', data: [16.3, 13.0, 22.3], bgColor: 'blue', hidden: false },
    { label: 'Squirrels', data: [5.8,3.1, 14.9], bgColor: 'cyan', hidden: false },
    { label: 'Bats', data: [0.1, 3.6, 2.6], bgColor: 'aquamarine', hidden: false }
  ]
};
const iLastDs = baseData.datasets.length - 1;

const data = {
  labels: baseData.datasets
    .map(() => baseData.labels)
    .map((labels, i) => i < iLastDs ? [...labels, null] : labels)
    .flatMap(v => v),
  datasets: [{
    data: baseData.datasets
      .map(ds => ds.data)
      .map((data, i) => i < iLastDs ? [...data, null] : data)
      .flatMap(v => v),
    backgroundColor: baseData.datasets
      .map(ds => ds.data.map(v => ds.bgColor))
      .map((bgColors, i) => i < iLastDs ? [...bgColors, null] : bgColors)
      .flatMap(v => v),
    categoryPercentage: 1,
    barPercentage: 0.9
  }]
};

const options = {
  maintainAspectRatio: true,
  responsive: true,
  interaction: {
    intersect: true,
    mode: 'index',
  },
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom',
      labels: {
        generateLabels: chart => baseData.datasets.map((ds, i) => ({
          datasetIndex: i,
          text: ds.label,
          fillStyle: ds.bgColor,
          strokeStyle: 'lightgray',
          hidden: baseData.datasets[i].hidden
        }))
      },
      onClick: (event, legendItem, legend) => {
        baseData.datasets[legendItem.datasetIndex].hidden = !baseData.datasets[legendItem.datasetIndex].hidden;
        const iFirstValue = legendItem.datasetIndex + legendItem.datasetIndex * baseData.labels.length;
        for (let i = iFirstValue; i < iFirstValue + baseData.labels.length; i++) {
          legend.chart.toggleDataVisibility(i);
        }
        legend.chart.update();
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      callbacks: {
        title: ctx => {
          const dsIndex = Math.floor(ctx[0].dataIndex / baseData.datasets.length);
          return baseData.datasets[dsIndex].label + ' / ' + ctx[0].label;
        }
      }
    }
  },
  scales: {
    x: {
      grid: {
        display: false
      }
    }, 
    y: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Horsepower',
      }
    }
  }
};

new Chart('mychart',  {
  type: 'bar',  
  data,
  options
});
```

```css
span {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.9.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="mychart" height="100"></canvas>  
<span>Source: Animals Index, June 2022</span>
```